# how to remove existing appended stringbuilder data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am reading data from database table using `SqlDataReader` and read data I going to append in `StringBuilder`. Here coming the already appended data.

So how to remove that data?

Comment: u mean data is appending to the existing data with out clearing it?

Comment: yes.....................

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Clear method of the string builder.  As in strbldr.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

I do think that the easiest way to clear is to set the [`Length` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length.aspx) to zero.

E.g.:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hello world.");

// Clear.
sb.Length = 0;
```

The [`Clear` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear.aspx) is only supported in the .NET Framework 4, not below e.g. not in the .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to erase/wipe/delete the existing data, then the recommendations by others will fit the bill, eg

```
sb.Clear();        // .Net 4 and above, or
sb.Length = 0;     // Older versions of .Net
```

However, if you're wanting to read/extract the appended data, then this will do it:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("a");
sb.Append("b");
var result = sb.ToString();    // result is now "ab"
```

Note that ToString doesn't clear the string builder, so if you want to reuse it, then you'll need to clear it as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

We can clear stringbuilder in 3 ways

1. Remove from the start of the StringBuilder by its length:`myStrBuild.Remove(0, myStrBuild.Length)`
2. Store the contents in another string and call Replace upon the stringbuilder using the string as a parameter: `string s = myStrBuild.ToString();
   myStrBuild.Replace(s, "");`
3. Or simply just set the Length property to zero. This property is not read -only.`myStrBuild.Length = 0;`

And in .Net 4.0 we can use  `myStrBuild.Clear()`